# Livecode : Save all imported images from current stack

Tags: livecode

Is there any way to download/save all the images imported on the current stack?

Other question: I can't open the stack created by latest version 7.0 using the Livecode 6.6.2. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Could you please explain what you do mean with "all the images imported on the current stack" ?

Answer (score 0):

> Other question: I can't open the stack created by latest version 7.0 using the Livecode 6.6.2. Is there any workaround?

In LC 7 under file menu select "Save as". In the following dialog you can select in which format you  want to save the stack. Select "Legacy Livecode Stack (5.5)" and save it. The stack can now be opened with LC 5.5 and higher.

Comment: This really should be submitted as a separate question. Matthias' answer is correct, however.

Answer (score 0):

The following handler in a button will export all of the images on the current card to the Desktop:

```
on mouseUp
  repeat with x = 1 to the number of images
      put the short name of img x into tImgName
      put img x into url ("binfile:/Users/asayd/Desktop/" & tImgName)
  end repeat
end mouseUp
```

Of course, you can specify any directory as the save location. If you want to export all of the images in a stack just add another repeat loop outside the first one:

```
on mouseUp
  repeat with y = 1 to the number of cards
     go card y
     repeat with x = 1 to the number of images
         put the short name of img x into tImgName
         put img x into url ("binfile:/Users/asayd/Desktop/" & tImgName)
     end repeat
  end repeat
end mouseUp
```